What is a suggested equation of fit for a line that is curved on log log axes?
I'm trying to fit a curve to the following log-log chart:-

I've tried Copilot and Brave's Leo, but they both misinterpret and suggest a power law of the form $y = ax^b$, which is a straight line.
What equation would include that little curved bit at the start please? Or perhaps two equations for the curved and straight parts.

Is there a bit more info—data, plots—you might share?

Based on that picture, considering that to be a straight line is absolutely the correct thing -- that looks like you have one, maybe two, data points that don't lie on an perfectly straight line (and those aren't that far off), and if those axis labels are correct you absolutely don't care about how your compression algorithm performs on a 10-byte file, but on how it scales as the file gets big.  (Edit: unless the point of the experiment is to show how this compression algo fails for small inputs, but then you wouldn't include the rightmost 95% of this graph.)

@tabstop Thanks. The entire purple line is formed from 100,000 points, concentrated towards the origin's end.

@PaulUszak Interesting! I would have expected (just based on what people usually care about) that you would have an expression for the size of the compressed file as, say, some small-ish number of bytes of overhead + some amount depending on the input, so for a big-O type estimate the first gets ignored. But if you're interested in trying to figure out where the first part takes over, I don't know if there's a nice way to tell that automatically from the data. (If you have a theoretical estimate of those values from the algo, then that would suggest where the switchover should be.)

The answer to your question depends on what you're trying to do. If theory predicts a linear relationship, then you should fit a line and note that the model breaks down toward the origin (interesting, something to research).

@CharlesHudgins The curve is empirical. The experiment is LZMA compression of totally pseudo-random data of various sizes to see if such might form a quick randomness test. I.e. if compressed size of test file < suggested empirical size => not random.

It did strike me as odd that this "compressed" file size was the same as the original file size, so that makes sense (that the algorithm can't compress it). I don't know details of LZMA, but I suspect that for small sizes you're seeing the effect of overhead that the algo has to write to the new file no matter what the original file looks like, and for larger files that impact disappears; so unless you're planning to only be checking < 50 bytes of your random generator at a time the main line would be your friend I would think.

@PaulUszak then yes, I would say that you're seeing big O notation in action. Looks like a power law for sufficiently large inputs with, as tabstop said, some algorithmic overhead for small inputs. I would take this as an indication that the test you propose is unreliable for small inputs because the asymptotic behavior has not yet kicked in. That is, you might not get a reliable signal for small inputs because the algorithmic overhead will show up in inputs random and nonrandom.

Hint.
Extract a random subset of points from the original set to minimize processing time, and then assuming the data is $\log$ transformed in both axes, you can fit a function like
$$
y(x) = (a-e^{b(x-x_0)})(c x + d)
$$
Follows MATHEMATICA script showing a plot with values to the parameters:
y[x_] := (a - Exp[b (x - x0)]) (c x + d)
x0 = -1/10;
a = 3;
b = -4;
c = 5;
d = -3;
Plot[y[x], {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]


